# What's the difference between initializing arrays in the constructor or in the declaration in PHP?

Tags: php

```
class X
{
    private $myVar;

    function __constructor()
    {
        this->myVar = array();
    }
}
```

or

```
class X
{
    private $myVar = array();

    function __constructor()
    {
    }
}
```

what's the difference? Which is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all intents and purposes, there's no practical difference, besides the obvious syntax difference. The array will behave the same, and all code depending on it will too.

If you want to get into edge cases, you'd see a difference if you ever *not* ran the constructor when instantiating the object (e.g. if you `extend` and override the constructor without calling `parent::__construct`). In the first case `$myVar` would be `null`, which may screw with code which depends on it being an array.

I'd suggest to always initialise while declaring the property, since it's less code, more obvious what your intend is with the variable, and you avoid weird edge cases as noted above.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is no performance difference but i would recommend doing this while declaring the class variable as it will give the idea of the variable's properties and access modifiers without having to read the entire code.

Answer (score 2):

Here, you didn't initialize anything, just typed your variable.
Initializing variables in attribute give you good visibility of your attributes type and set your custom default values depending in your business logic, instead of `NULL` given by **PHP**
In term of performance and this is my personal opinion, there is no difference in your example.